# Mobilink with MySQL on Linux

Tags: mysql, linux, odbc, sqlanywhere, mobilink

I'm trying to configure MobiLink to work with my MySQL database on localhost.

I am using:
- mysql-connector-odbc-5.1.10
- SQL Anywhere 12.0.1 Developer Edition

I'm following this tutorial http://www.sybase.com/detail?id=1056497, but working on Linux Mint 11 x64.

I have installed Mobilink, configured ODBC connector for my MySQL database, and now i try to start MobiLink Synchronization Server using this command:

```
/bin64s/mlsrv12 -v+ -o mlsrv.out -zs ml_mysql -c "DSN=sa11_ML-connector;uid=root;pwd=my_pass" -dl -zu+ -x tcpip{port=2639}
```

I am receiving this error:

```
(...)
I. 2012-03-28 01:25:50. <Main> Timeout for inactive database connections: 60 minutes
I. 2012-03-28 01:25:50. <Main> Maximum delay between retries after deadlock: 30 seconds
I. 2012-03-28 01:25:50. <Main> Rowset size: 10
I. 2012-03-28 01:25:50. <Main> Number of database worker threads: 5
W. 2012-03-28 01:25:50. <Main> [10064] Unknown users will be added automatically (when there is no authenticate_user script)
Unable to load 'MySQL ODBC 5.1 Driver' errno=2
I. 2012-03-28 01:25:50. <Main> Shared administrative connection connected
I. 2012-03-28 01:25:50. <Main> System event on shared administrative connection:
                    SELECT count(*) FROM ml_scripts_modified
I. 2012-03-28 01:25:50. <Main> Translated SQL:
                    SELECT count(*) FROM ml_scripts_modified
E. 2012-03-28 01:25:50. <Main> [-10379] The ODBC connection string specifies a driver that is not compatible with 64-bit MobiLink
I. 2012-03-28 01:25:50. <Main> Shared administrative connection disconnected
E. 2012-03-28 01:25:50. <Main> [-10382] The MobiLink Server has failed to start
```

I have downloaded the newest ODBC Connector from here: http://dev.mysql.com/downloads/connector/odbc/5.1.html, and tried 
- Generic Linux (x86, 32-bit), RPM Package
- Linux ver. .3.glibc2 (x86, 64-bit), Compressed TAR Archive

Both of them returns that error, and should be fully compatibile with  MobiLink x64 (I thought so...).

Any ideas?

Cheers.

---

I've copied odbc config file into another location (found in strace, that MobiLink scanns ~/.ODBC.ini for config file) but now I'm getting another error...

```
I. 2012-03-28 15:45:21. SQL Anywhere MobiLink Server Version 12.0.1.3457
I. 2012-03-28 15:45:21. 
I. 2012-03-28 15:45:21. Copyright (c) 2001-2011, iAnywhere Solutions, Inc.
I. 2012-03-28 15:45:21. Portions copyright (c) 1988-2011, Sybase, Inc. All rights reserved.
I. 2012-03-28 15:45:21. Use of this software is governed by the Sybase License Agreement.
I. 2012-03-28 15:45:21. Refer to http://www.sybase.com/softwarelicenses.
I. 2012-03-28 15:45:21. 
I. 2012-03-28 15:45:21. This server is licensed to:
I. 2012-03-28 15:45:21.     Developer Edition
I. 2012-03-28 15:45:21.     Restricted Use
I. 2012-03-28 15:45:21. Running Linux 2.6.38-13-generic #57-Ubuntu SMP Mon Mar 5 18:29:54 UTC 2012 on X86_64
I. 2012-03-28 15:45:21. Server built for X86_64 processor architecture
I. 2012-03-28 15:45:21. <Main> Option 1: -v+
I. 2012-03-28 15:45:21. <Main> Option 2: -o
I. 2012-03-28 15:45:21. <Main> Option 3: mlsrv.out
I. 2012-03-28 15:45:21. <Main> Option 4: -zs
I. 2012-03-28 15:45:21. <Main> Option 5: ml_mysql
I. 2012-03-28 15:45:21. <Main> Option 6: -c
I. 2012-03-28 15:45:21. <Main> Option 7: DSN=sa11_ML-connector;uid=root;pwd=********
I. 2012-03-28 15:45:21. <Main> Option 8: -dl
I. 2012-03-28 15:45:21. <Main> Option 9: -zu+
I. 2012-03-28 15:45:21. <Main> Option 10: -x
I. 2012-03-28 15:45:21. <Main> Option 11: tcpip{port=2639}
I. 2012-03-28 15:45:21. <Main> Verbose logging: show upload row values
I. 2012-03-28 15:45:21. <Main> Verbose logging: show download row values
I. 2012-03-28 15:45:21. <Main> Verbose logging: show script names when invoked
I. 2012-03-28 15:45:21. <Main> Verbose logging: show script contents when invoked
I. 2012-03-28 15:45:21. <Main> Verbose logging: show schema for each table
I. 2012-03-28 15:45:21. <Main> Verbose logging: show an error when the first read of a synchronization fails
I. 2012-03-28 15:45:21. <Main> Verbose logging: show translated SQL for prepared statements
I. 2012-03-28 15:45:21. <Main> Verbose logging: show rowcount values
I. 2012-03-28 15:45:21. <Main> Cache size: 52428800 bytes
I. 2012-03-28 15:45:21. <Main> Download cache directory size: 10485760 bytes
I. 2012-03-28 15:45:21. <Main> Local file for remote synchronization logs: 'mlsrv.mle'
I. 2012-03-28 15:45:21. <Main> Starting cache sizes: min of 52428800 bytes; max of 2906351616 bytes; initial size of 52064256 bytes
I. 2012-03-28 15:45:21. <Main> Individual database connections will be closed after synchronization errors
I. 2012-03-28 15:45:21. <Main> Maximum number of BLOB bytes to compare: 4294967295
I. 2012-03-28 15:45:21. <Main> Maximum number of database connections: 5
I. 2012-03-28 15:45:21. <Main> Maximum number of deadlock retries: 10
I. 2012-03-28 15:45:21. <Main> Timeout for inactive database connections: 60 minutes
I. 2012-03-28 15:45:21. <Main> Maximum delay between retries after deadlock: 30 seconds
I. 2012-03-28 15:45:21. <Main> Rowset size: 10
I. 2012-03-28 15:45:21. <Main> Number of database worker threads: 5
W. 2012-03-28 15:45:21. <Main> [10064] Unknown users will be added automatically (when there is no authenticate_user script)
Unable to load '/usr/lib64/libmyodbc5.so' errno=0
I. 2012-03-28 15:45:21. <Main> Shared administrative connection connected
I. 2012-03-28 15:45:21. <Main> System event on shared administrative connection:
                        SELECT count(*) FROM ml_scripts_modified
I. 2012-03-28 15:45:21. <Main> Translated SQL:
                        SELECT count(*) FROM ml_scripts_modified
I. 2012-03-28 15:45:21. <Main> ODBC DBMS Name: MySQL
I. 2012-03-28 15:45:21. <Main> ODBC DBMS Version: 5.1.61-0ubuntu0.11.04.1
I. 2012-03-28 15:45:21. <Main> ODBC DBMS Driver Version: 05.01.0010
I. 2012-03-28 15:45:21. <Main> ODBC Version supported by the driver: 3.51
I. 2012-03-28 15:45:21. <Main> Collation sequence of the consolidated database is 'utf8_general_ci'
I. 2012-03-28 15:45:21. <Main> ODBC DBMS Type: MySQL
I. 2012-03-28 15:45:21. <Main> System event on shared administrative connection:
                        set innodb_table_locks = 0
I. 2012-03-28 15:45:21. <Main> Translated SQL:
                        set innodb_table_locks = 0
I. 2012-03-28 15:45:21. <Main> ODBC isolation set to: Read Committed
I. 2012-03-28 15:45:21. <Main> System event on shared administrative connection:
                        SELECT user_id, name, hashed_password FROM ml_user WHERE 1=2
I. 2012-03-28 15:45:21. <Main> Translated SQL:
                        SELECT user_id, name, hashed_password FROM ml_user WHERE 1=2
I. 2012-03-28 15:45:21. <Main> System event on shared administrative connection:
                        SELECT rid, remote_id, script_ldt, description FROM ml_database WHERE 1=2
I. 2012-03-28 15:45:21. <Main> Translated SQL:
                        SELECT rid, remote_id, script_ldt, description FROM ml_database WHERE 1=2
I. 2012-03-28 15:45:21. <Main> System event on shared administrative connection:
                        SELECT rid, subscription_id, user_id, progress, publication_name, last_upload_time, last_download_time FROM ml_subscription WHERE 1=2
I. 2012-03-28 15:45:21. <Main> Translated SQL:
                        SELECT rid, subscription_id, user_id, progress, publication_name, last_upload_time, last_download_time FROM ml_subscription WHERE 1=2
I. 2012-03-28 15:45:21. <Main> System event on shared administrative connection:
                        SELECT table_id, name FROM ml_table WHERE 1=2
I. 2012-03-28 15:45:21. <Main> Translated SQL:
                        SELECT table_id, name FROM ml_table WHERE 1=2
I. 2012-03-28 15:45:21. <Main> System event on shared administrative connection:
                        SELECT component_name, property_set_name, property_name, property_value FROM ml_property WHERE 1=2
I. 2012-03-28 15:45:21. <Main> Translated SQL:
                        SELECT component_name, property_set_name, property_name, property_value FROM ml_property WHERE 1=2
I. 2012-03-28 15:45:21. <Main> System event on shared administrative connection:
                        SELECT script_id, script, script_language FROM ml_script WHERE 1=2
I. 2012-03-28 15:45:21. <Main> Translated SQL:
                        SELECT script_id, script, script_language FROM ml_script WHERE 1=2
I. 2012-03-28 15:45:21. <Main> System event on shared administrative connection:
                        SELECT version_id, name, description FROM ml_script_version WHERE 1=2
I. 2012-03-28 15:45:21. <Main> Translated SQL:
                        SELECT version_id, name, description FROM ml_script_version WHERE 1=2
I. 2012-03-28 15:45:21. <Main> System event on shared administrative connection:
                        SELECT version_id, event, script_id FROM ml_connection_script WHERE 1=2
I. 2012-03-28 15:45:21. <Main> Translated SQL:
                        SELECT version_id, event, script_id FROM ml_connection_script WHERE 1=2
I. 2012-03-28 15:45:21. <Main> System event on shared administrative connection:
                        SELECT version_id, table_id, event, script_id FROM ml_table_script WHERE 1=2
I. 2012-03-28 15:45:21. <Main> Translated SQL:
                        SELECT version_id, table_id, event, script_id FROM ml_table_script WHERE 1=2
I. 2012-03-28 15:45:21. <Main> System event on shared administrative connection:
                        SELECT last_modified FROM ml_scripts_modified WHERE 1=2
I. 2012-03-28 15:45:21. <Main> Translated SQL:
                        SELECT last_modified FROM ml_scripts_modified WHERE 1=2
I. 2012-03-28 15:45:21. <Main> System event on shared administrative connection:
                        SELECT version_id, table_id, idx, name, type FROM ml_column WHERE 1=2
I. 2012-03-28 15:45:21. <Main> Translated SQL:
                        SELECT version_id, table_id, idx, name, type FROM ml_column WHERE 1=2
I. 2012-03-28 15:45:21. <Main> System event on shared administrative connection:
                        SELECT server_id, name, connection_info, instance_key, start_time FROM ml_primary_server WHERE 1=2
I. 2012-03-28 15:45:21. <Main> Translated SQL:
                        SELECT server_id, name, connection_info, instance_key, start_time FROM ml_primary_server WHERE 1=2
I. 2012-03-28 15:45:21. <Main> System event on shared administrative connection:
                        SELECT script_id, script_name, flags, affected_pubs, script, description FROM ml_passthrough_script WHERE 1=2
I. 2012-03-28 15:45:21. <Main> Translated SQL:
                        SELECT script_id, script_name, flags, affected_pubs, script, description FROM ml_passthrough_script WHERE 1=2
I. 2012-03-28 15:45:21. <Main> System event on shared administrative connection:
                        SELECT remote_id, run_order, script_id, last_modified FROM ml_passthrough WHERE 1=2
I. 2012-03-28 15:45:21. <Main> Translated SQL:
                        SELECT remote_id, run_order, script_id, last_modified FROM ml_passthrough WHERE 1=2
I. 2012-03-28 15:45:21. <Main> System event on shared administrative connection:
                        SELECT status_id, remote_id, run_order, script_id, script_status, error_code, error_text, remote_run_time FROM ml_passthrough_status WHERE 1=2
I. 2012-03-28 15:45:21. <Main> Translated SQL:
                        SELECT status_id, remote_id, run_order, script_id, script_status, error_code, error_text, remote_run_time FROM ml_passthrough_status WHERE 1=2
I. 2012-03-28 15:45:21. <Main> System event on shared administrative connection:
                        SELECT failed_script_id, error_code, new_script_id, action FROM ml_passthrough_repair WHERE 1=2
I. 2012-03-28 15:45:21. <Main> Translated SQL:
                        SELECT failed_script_id, error_code, new_script_id, action FROM ml_passthrough_repair WHERE 1=2
I. 2012-03-28 15:45:21. <Main> System event on shared administrative connection:
                        SELECT count(*) FROM ml_scripts_modified
I. 2012-03-28 15:45:21. <Main> Translated SQL:
                        SELECT count(*) FROM ml_scripts_modified
I. 2012-03-28 15:45:21. <Main> This software is using security technology from Certicom Corp.
I. 2012-03-28 15:45:21. <Main> System event on shared administrative connection:
                        SELECT property_set_name, property_name, property_value FROM ml_property WHERE component_name = ? ORDER BY property_set_name 
I. 2012-03-28 15:45:21. <Main> Translated SQL:
                        SELECT property_set_name, property_name, property_value FROM ml_property WHERE component_name = ? ORDER BY property_set_name 
I. 2012-03-28 15:45:21. <Main> Notifier stage connection connected
I. 2012-03-28 15:45:21. <Main> System event on the notifier stage connection:
                        set innodb_table_locks = 0
I. 2012-03-28 15:45:21. <Main> Translated SQL:
                        set innodb_table_locks = 0
I. 2012-03-28 15:45:21. <Main> MobiLink server started
Press 'q' to quit MobiLink server
Interrupted
```

It seems like it is now using my database, but still there is:

```
W. 2012-03-28 15:45:21. <Main> [10064] Unknown users will be added automatically (when there is no authenticate_user script)
    Unable to load '/usr/lib64/libmyodbc5.so' errno=0
```

Under /usr/lib64/libmyodbc5.so is my ODBC-driver.

Comment: `errno=2` translates to `No such file or directory`. If you `strace(1)` your program, you might be able to tell which specific file it is trying to access, and symlink or otherwise fix the problem.

Comment: Yikes, sorry, I didn't mean to post the whole thing; `strace(1)` only grabs _portions_ of system call data, but it might have captured some portion of passwords or keys. Please either validate the output to make sure it doesn't contain private data or change passwords and credentials if necessary. (I had just hoped you'd spot the missing ODBC driver somewhere in there...)

Comment: Unfortunately now I can't find anything interesting in it (even if it is there), I'll analyze it later. (And I tried to scan it for passwords before.)

Answer (score 0):

Make sure that you are using the [recommended MySQL ODBC driver](http://www.sybase.com/detail?id=1091677#_MY_SQL) and following the notes for using that driver with MobiLink.

[Other ways to get help with SQL Anywhere and MobiLink.](http://dcx.sybase.com/index.html#1201/en/sausinghelp/uh-findoutmore.html)